# How to use a USB Sim adapter to send SMS on Linux Debian?

Tags: networking, usb, debian, wwan, hsdpa

I have a this [`USB USDPA 7.2Mbps Wireless Data Card`](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32860631296.html?src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=631-313-3945&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Gploogle_7_shopping&aff_atform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&albcp=9867207072&albag=103142452067&trgt=906403778784&crea=fr32860631296&netw=u&device=c&albpg=906403778784&albpd=fr32860631296&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI056xzcHa6wIVAs53Ch1cbAhDEAYYASABEgLPYvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) with a SIM card.

I want to use it on Linux Debian to send SMS.

When I do `lsusb`, this is my Device:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c6:1000 Qualcomm, Inc. Mass Storage Device
```

I have tried to use modswitch with the help of this [article](https://www.mageialinux-online.org/forum/topic-25608+usb_modeswitch-et-cle-3g4g-05c6-1000-05c6-6000.php)

````bsh
sudo usb_modeswitch -W -v 05c6 -p 1000 -K
Take all parameters from the command line


 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.5.2 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x05c6
DefaultProduct= 0x1000

StandardEject=1

Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 04b4:0510
  found USB ID 1af3:0001
  found USB ID 05c6:1000
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 002 on bus 001
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
 with class 8
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
     Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
  Serial No.: 351602000025260
-------------------------
Sending standard EJECT sequence
Looking for active drivers ...
 OK, driver detached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 0
Trying to send message 2 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 2 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 0
Trying to send message 3 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 3 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 1
Trying to send message 4 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 4 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 1
Reset response endpoint 0x81
Reset message endpoint 0x01
 Could not reset endpoint (probably harmless): -4
 Device is gone, skip any further commands
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!

)

This is the result of the command `sudo usb_modeswitch -W -v 05c6 -p 1000 -K`:

```bash
sudo usb_modeswitch -W -v 05c6 -p 1000 -K
Take all parameters from the command line


 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.5.2 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x05c6
DefaultProduct= 0x1000

StandardEject=1

Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 04b4:0510
  found USB ID 1af3:0001
  found USB ID 05c6:1000
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 002 on bus 001
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
 with class 8
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
     Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
  Serial No.: 351602000025260
-------------------------
Sending standard EJECT sequence
Looking for active drivers ...
 OK, driver detached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 0
Trying to send message 2 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 2 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 0
Trying to send message 3 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 3 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 1
Trying to send message 4 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 4 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 1
Reset response endpoint 0x81
Reset message endpoint 0x01
 Could not reset endpoint (probably harmless): -4
 Device is gone, skip any further commands
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
````

Now, `lsusb` show this device:

```bsh
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c6:6000 Qualcomm, Inc. Siemens SG75
```

Did it work? Is it persistent?

```bsh
$ ls /dev/ | grep USB
ttyUSB0
ttyUSB1
ttyUSB2
ttyUSB3
```

- Where should I start please?

Does this card have a specific driver for linux?

Comment: Everything I have seen for this card (I have a HUAWEI card myself) says the drivers are on the card. When you insert the card, can you find a Linux folder?

Comment: When I do `df -h` I can't see any drive. Can you share me the link?

Comment: I googled for that USB Key, and looked at many possibilities. I could not see a Linux driver so if not on the key itself, it probably does not work in Linux.

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://www.mageialinux-online.org/forum/topic-25608+usb_modeswitch-et-cle-3g4g-05c6-1000-05c6-6000.php , with the help of it I have now `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c6:6000 Qualcomm, Inc. Siemens SG75
`

Comment: I have not seen that or even know who the card maker is. If they have a Linux driver , try it.

Comment: I can connect in 3g with it so it work, now I want to know which one to use to send sms, `ttyUSB0` or `ttyUSB1`, or `ttyUSB2` or `ttyUSB3`, do you know how i can do ?

Comment: I cannot answer the SMS question.  You would need the manufacturer’s documentation for that.

Comment: I have the `ttyUSB` which is the protocole for communicated with at device, I can already read received sms, I just can't send them, `error: couldn't send the SMS: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Message.SmscAddressUnknown: SMSC address unknown'`

Comment: I figured out how to send sms, so it work on linux, with mmcli, how can I set the default smsc?